# Magento2: How can you check/set which Elasticsearch index is currently being used

Tags: magento2.3, reindex, elasticsearch

We have a large catalog (400k products) that takes a day or two to reindex.

Occasionally I've had something go wrong with the indexing process and then nothing is searchable (code errors). I don't want the site down for days if this happens, so I'd like to clone the current index, then start the Magento reindexing, and if something goes haywire, restore the backup index.

I can't find how to see/overwrite which version of the index is currently being used.

Comment: we have over 300k products and it takes about 5 min to reindex. what is your server config!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the index is specified by an alias in the actual query: magento2_product_1 in our case, which points to the current actual index: magento2_product_1_v38.

I can see the indexes by running this curl statement:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cat/aliases?v=true&pretty"
```